# How does C# handle overlapping System.Drawing.Regions regions?

Tags: image

I'm creating a Jigsaw Puzzle game as my first  C# program (3 weeks self-taught so far) and I've come far along in it, to the point where I can take a bitmap, split it into images, and make sections of each of the images transparent where needed. I have an array of points that indicate the sides of the pieces, and drawing the borders is just fine. A **Graphics Path** will encapsulate these points and a **Region** will take the Path object as a parameter that defines it.

My question is, how does C# handle overlapping System.Drawing Regions when it comes to hit detection? If one region overlaps another, will both regions respond with a hit or will the one that was drawn last get the hit?

I got the idea from reading this tutorial. 2D/RegionIsVisible.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0480_2D/RegionIsVisible.htm and realizing I can call the isVisible() method to determine what group of pieces to move. Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a better solution to this problem just using GraphicsPath instead of bothering with using a Region. Overlapping is not an issue. All that MouseEvents care about is the location that you click in. Any GraphicsPath construct, whether or not it overlaps another one, is fair game.

Anyway, the problem is solved. Overlapping Regions or GraphicsPath's that intersect are a non-issue!

Current progress from my C# troubleshooting game. All tabs are rectangular for now, but converting the program to have curved tabs should be a piece of cake with my new understanding: